# Стратегия удаления просроченных записей

Tags: архитектура

Есть некоторое хранилище кодов доступа, каждый из которых обладает двумя свойствами - временем истечения и количеством попыток подтверждения этого кода. После того, как любой из этих параметров так или иначе истек, код уже нельзя использовать, и его необходимо удалить из БД. Тут я вижу две стратегии, как с ним поступить:

- Удалять код при запросе этого кода из БД. Плюсы: нет фоновых задач, минусы: race conditions (кто-то может получить запись с retries = 1 в тот момент, когда кто-то в параллель пытается подтвердить тот же код) и объемный код простого получения записи
- Написать background-worker, который будет постоянно обходить базу на предмет нахождения устаревших записей. Плюсы: получение записей происходит как обычно (остаются проверки на валидность записи, но не нужно вызывать ее удаление), минусы: некоторый лаг и существование фоновых воркеров, все те же race conditions.

Обе стратегии мне кажутся дурацкими, и я не могу придумать, как правильно решить задачу (хотя мне кажется, что есть более очевидное решение, способное свести лаг к минимуму). Само приложение распределенное, но использование сервиса распределенных блокировок вполне допустимо (однако само по себе его использование спасет только от race conditions).

Какая стратегия будет наиболее правильной для удаления подобных записей?

Comment: Обычно это делается скриптом, который запускается сервисом `cron`.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, это как раз второй вариант с _Написать background-worker,_

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics конкретная платформа - java, так что выделить тред с планировщикомм проблемы не стоит, проблема в том, что это создает фоновую нагрузку, которую сложно правильно рассчитать, и вообще добавляет фоновый контекст в приложение.

Comment: Вариант от WordPress: при очередном запросе выполнять лимитированный по объёму maintenance. Например, проверить максимум N других ключей, и удалить при необходимости.

Comment: @Sergiks мы не можем терять записи ни при каких условиях (в случае с AOF этот сценарий вероятен), к тому же конкретно редис вбивает в кол в другие вещи типа масштабируемости (это решается каким-нибудь аэроспайком, но все данные у нас хранятся только в полноценной БД - это политическое решение).

Comment: Полноценная БД не поддерживает Lock'и и транзакции для избежания race condition?

Comment: @Sergiks транзакции - да, про них даже не подумал. Но в вопросе race condition на самом деле потому, что оба предложенных варианта несут примерно одинаковый запас боли, сервис распределенных локов в проекте есть (consul), и считается, что у него стопроцентный аптайм и без него приложение не работает.

Answer (score 4):

Проверка кода должна выполняться транзакцией с одновременным декрементов попыток. Это поможет избежать race condition.

```
Начать транзакцию
  Получить ключ
  Нет ключа? – вернуть FALSE
  Счётчик оставшихся попыток больше 1?
  Нет – удалить запись и вернуть TRUE
  Уменьшить счётчик
  Вернуть TRUE
Конец транзакции
```

Если БД не поддерживает Lock'и можно имитировать их механизм, записывая в доп. поле случайную величину как ключ эксклюзивной сессии клиента.

---

**Вариант, который не подошёл**

Держать коды в Redis, с указанием времени истечения хранения. В значении хранить кол-во использований и время истечения.

Просроченные ключи удалит сам Redis или скрипт при просроченном запросе (если Redis протормозит почему-то, и значение как-то выживет). Так же удалять ключи при последней, по счётчику, допустимой попытке использования.

UPd. Масштабируемость возможна – посмотрите предложенное решение для распределённых lock'ов: [distributed locks with Redis](http://redis.io/topics/distlock).

Comment: Я описал (пусть и не очень полно) выше вариант с синхронным получением одного и того же кода двумя консьюмерами, в ходе которого последняя попытка используется де-факто двумя приложениями. Это маловероятная ситуация, но я просто хочу написать этот компонент изначально бронебойным и не делать при этом непрозрачную архитектуру.

Comment: Проблема масштабируемости не в распределенных локах, а в том, что эта штука однопоточна и не подразумевает шардинга из коробки, поэтому в нее можно упереться, и де-факто это классический SPOF. Опять же, aerospike решает все эти проблемы, но мне не в слое кэширования надо хранить и обрабатывать записи. Кроме того, redlock - ненадежный алгоритм (достаточно выхода из строя всего одного сервера, чтобы локи начали проваливаться), для этого есть consul, etcd (на самом деле paxos, vr, raft) и прочее.

Comment: В случае с локами на нормальной sql базе, не должно возникать такой проблемы (к примеру в постгресе есть SELECT ... FOR UPDATE), при условии, что приложение не ломится каждый раз на разный сервер. В случае редиса - для того, чтобы последнюю попытку нельзя было использовать несколько раз - достаточно проверять возврат декремента (в крайнем случае, редис возвращает разные коды для удаления записи и попытки удаления несуществующей записи). Шардинг в редисе на уровне приложения прикручивается не то, чтобы слишком геморно, правда про резервирование не берусь утверждать.

Answer (score 1):

В результате длинной головоболи, которую я придумал себе сам, было решено делать очищающие бекграунд-воркеры плюс удаление на лету там, где это возможно - это решение возникло просто из-за того, что в проекте подразумевается постраничный вывод, а фильтрация страниц на лету превращается в совсем уж дикий ад и (теоретически) может препятствовать прогрессу выполнения. Поэтому получилось комбинированное (и, не скрою, болезненное) решение, которое безусловно, не является ожидаемо волшебным.

Что до идеальной инфраструктуры, то тут на самом деле прав Sergiks - вся боль исчезает, если лишние записи фильтруются на уровне самого хранилища, неважно, redis это, couchbase или aerospike. Теоретически, этот уровень можно воспроизвести дополнительным слоем менеджеров внутри приложения, но это настолько же болезненная процедура, и остается только надеяться, что практика создания записей с ttl получит более широкое применение в базах данных.